# neo4j find paths between nodes with with the fewest stages

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I start to learn neo4j. I am using the graph

http://neo4j.com/graphgist/b1f6439d-2904-4fcf-8017-8c83d57ef20b#listing_category=sports-and-recreation

and I have a small issue. I do not know how to find routes that you can get from Darjeeling to Sandakphu with the fewest stages

Could anyone see how should be build correct query, should I use shortest path function?

Currently I'm testing something like:

```
MATCH (p:peak{name:'Sandakphu'})-[r*..5]-(t:town{name:'Darjeeling'}) 
RETURN r
MATCH path = ShortestPath((p)-[*..5])-(t)]
RETURN path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 MATCH (p:peak{name:'Sandakphu'}), (t:town{name:'Darjeeling'}) 
 MATCH path = ShortestPath((p)-[*..5]-(t))
 RETURN path
```